# Guidance on efficient SQL many-to-many join query with multiple filters

Tags: sql, database, performance, optimization

I could use some guidance in building an optimized and efficient SQL query for the following entities:

```
1. Product:
 - id
 - state (active/archived)

2. Category:
 - id
 - name (e.g. Toiletries)

3. ProductCategory:
 - pid references Product.id
 - cid references Category.id
```

The target use case is to retrieve a list of products in a list of category ids and with `state = 'active'`

Now I have 3 options:

1. Filter product where state = 'active' and ProductCategory where cid in input category IDs (as subqueries?) and join the 2 results
2. Filter product where state = 'active' first, left join ProductCategory, then filter the results where cid in input category IDs
3. Filter ProductCategory where cid in input category IDs, left join Products table, filter by state = 'active'
4. Did I miss any?

My question is what query/filter strategy is recommended here, and why? Assume numProducts >>>> numCategories, numProducts < numProductCategories, since 1 product can have many categories.

Comment: You don't need to think about order of joins/ filtering. Databases work out the fastest startegy for you. You just tell it what you need in a SQL Query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your SQL returns the right result then there is no right or wrong way of writing it - and how long it takes to run would be dependent on a lot of information you haven't supplied such as indexes and data volumes.

If your chosen solution takes longer to run than you expected then it may be possible to tune it but we'd need to see the EXPLAIN PLAN for your query as well as the DDL for your tables.

In addition, SQL is a declarative language not a procedural one. This means it declares what the result is that you want, not how to achieve that result. The query optimiser decides how to achieve the result so, in theory, all the ways that you've shown for writing the SQL could end up with exactly the same execution plan

Comment: Makes sense SQL being declarative, however i've also heard people say things like "filter before join" so how you formulate the query would have to matter at some point right? for instance if you have a subquery in a query the subquery has to be executed first. In cases like that one would need to take optimization into account?

Comment: I would say if you logically structure your query to be as efficient as possible (I.e. reduce the volume of data as early as possible, use indexed columns/partitions) then you’re giving the best possible starting point to the query optimiser in order for it to do its thing. But then you should be logically structuring your query, and keeping it as simple as possible, anyway

Comment: Yeah, thats the reason for my question I suppose - by joining 2 filtering subqueries i thought it would help minimize the number of rows before the join, and wasn't sure if it would somehow outperform the other idea, where the join would happen first before the filter if you know what I mean. (for context there are no additional indexes other than the PKs)

Answer (score 0):

If there's clear results displayed and data is filled in all table
better for use 'JOIN. 'for one to one relationship, use join is better solution:

This best please try:

```sql
    select B.* 
    from category A
        inner join ProductCategory B
            on a.id = b.cid
        inner join product C
            on c.id = B.pid
    Where C.state ='active'
```

Answer (score 0):

For many to many join, 'CTE' and 'Exist' is better solution :

please try :

```
 with PC as
 ( 
  select A.* , B.pid
    from category A
       inner join ProductCategory B
        on A.id = B.cid),
  Product_Exist as
  (
    select * 
    from PC A 
    where exists(
        select * 
        from product B
        where A.pid = B.id
        and B.state ='active')
   )
   select [id], [Name] from Product_Exist;
```